# BOOTMGR is missing при установке Win 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, установка, bios

Подскажите, такая проблема: есть ПК, в нем жесткий диск с Win 7. Мне нужно на другой жесткий диск (далее ЖД) поставить тоже Win 7. Я подключил второй ЖД и форматнул его. Потом отключил свой основной ЖД, оставив чистый второй, а в привод вставил диск установочный с WIN 7. 
Естественно в биосе первым делом выставлена загрузка с CD привода.
При загрузке выдает ошибку "BOOTMGR is missing". Как я почитал, я при форматировании удалил какую-то ценную прогу типа загрузчика или что-то типа того.
Теперь вопрос: что мне со всем этим делать теперь?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по всему, проблема в CD. Если образ диска брали из интернета, попробуйте прожечь диск через программу UltraISO, либо установиться с флешки, подробнее о том как сделать флешку загрузочной [тут](http://vindavoz.ru/windows7/stati7/8-3-sposoba-ustanovit-windows-7-s-fleshki-sozdanie-zagruzochnoy-fleshki.html)